# How to clear the previous figure before the new one comes in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have implemented a program wherein the code is as follows

```
load('color_0.mat')
isosurface(foo,fo);
caxis([0.2 0.5])
colorbar
grid on; axis equal; colormap default; alpha(0.3);
hold on;  

plot3(35,30,15,'.','Color',[0,0,0],'MarkerSize',15); hold on; % Dorsal Raphe Nucleus  (DRN - serotonin, 5-HT)

xlabel('anterior-posterior (a.u.)'); ylabel('left-right (a.u.)'); zlabel('ventral-dorsal/inferior-superior (a.u.)'); 
grid on;

pause(.5)

load('color_1.mat')
isosurface(foo,fo);
caxis([0.2 0.5])
colorbar
grid on; axis equal; colormap default;  alpha(0.3);
hold on;  

plot3(35,30,15,'.','Color',[0,0,0],'MarkerSize',15); hold on; % Dorsal Raphe Nucleus (DRN - serotonin, 5-HT)

xlabel('anterior-posterior (a.u.)'); ylabel('left-right (a.u.)'); zlabel('ventral-dorsal/inferior-superior (a.u.)'); 
grid on;
```

This way the figure is being superimposed by the new one. How to avoid this? By using clf in between, the toolbar vanishes.

Answer (score 5):

The plots are superimposed because you're using `hold on`. Insert `hold off` in between plots so that new plots clear the old ones.

Comment: by using hold off...i am not getting any figure at all.

Comment: The `isosurface` does not clear the previous plot. So even when `hold` is `off`, the `isosurface` superimposes the previous one. As [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17618150/1698972) to the asker's next question, the axes must get cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Eitan T answer is correct. If you still want to use `hold on` because you want to keep certain elements on, but not others, you can give an handle to the element when you plot it:

```
h = plot3(35,30,15,'.','Color',[0,0,0],'MarkerSize',15);
```

and then clearing it by using:

```
delete(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to add `drawnow` right after `plot` to force all the content of the figure to be drawn on the screen.