# Clearing isosurface (or other plots) from an axes

Tags: matlab, plot

I use the following command:

```
isosurface(data,color)
```

Now if I use the same command with different data *again*, it gets **superimposed** on the previous one.

So, I tried doing:

```
p = patch(isosurface(foo));
isonormals(foo,p)
delete(p);
```

to delete the previous plot, but this way i can't use the `colorbar`.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
cla(gca)
```

[`cla`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html) clears an axes and [`gca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) is the handle to the *current axes* you're are plotting on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want another patch plot in the same figure window, just use

```
hold off
```

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand. U mean with the first method or the second method?

Comment: Default behaviour in Matlab when usng any plot type function, is to replace any existing plot in the active figure window with the new plot. Unless you specify "hold on" in which case the new plot will be superimposed on whatever is already in the window.